# Is there a way I can simplify this regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression for checking the validation of a textbox value. It works as I want it to, but I think that there might be a simpler way to do it.

Here is the regex:

```
@"^(?![0-9]+$)(?![0-9- `'-,]+$)(?![- `'-,]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9- `'-,]*$"
```

Here is what it does:

- `as-d'' 12 3` (allowed)
- `123''123` (not allowed)
- `abc---`(allowed)
- `123--123--123`(not allowed)
- `avsa123`(allowed)
- `''''` (not allowed)

**Allowed:**

- Letters on their own
- letters and specified special characters
- letters and numbers
- letters, numbers, and specified special characters

**Not Allowed:**

- Numbers on their own
- specified special characters on their own
- specified special characters and numbers
- just spaces

Is there a simpler way to write this expression?

Comment: Can rule be simplified to "Letters must be included"?

Comment: thats kind of what I was thinking, but I also need to specify that it can allow those specific characters as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rule can be simplified to "Letters must be included" then you can use regex like this:

```
^.*[a-zA-Z].*$
```

It accepts any string, but at least one alphabet character must be at somewhere. If you need to remove specific characters you can change `.`.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 /* more characters */ ]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 /* more characters */ ]*$
```

Comment: this only works if the string doesnt start with a character like `asd'asd`. But if you do `'asd`, it does not allow it

Comment: @mikeGear You mean it should or shouldn't start with specific character? Can you specify it in question?

Comment: What I mean is, it should allow `'asd`, but it doesn't. But your regex only allows special characters and numbers when the first value in the string is a letter

Comment: @mike If you're talking about upper one, it allows ```'asd``` since regex starts with ```.*```. Lower one doesn't accept it if you don't add wanted characters in ```/* more characters */``` part.

Comment: oh sorry, I missunderstood what this meant `/* more characters */`